# print last '\n' char using print method in python

Tags: python, printing, newline, stdout

Imagine I have the following code in file `test.py`:

```
for x in range(1,11):
     print x
```

This will print:

```
$myuser: python test.py
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
$myuser:
```

However, I want it to print:

```
$myuser: python test.py
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

$myuser:
```

Notice the last '\n' char, that is missing in the normal case. How do I get this last newline char?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing is missing; if there wasn't a newline at the end the last line would look like `10$myuser:`

Perhaps you want:

```
for x in range(1,11):
  print x
print
```

Answer (score 3):

Just put a bare `print` after the loop.

Comment: that seems sloppy, i was hoping for something more elegant. I think Adam might be right with his answer, however. I think i overlooked that detail.

Comment: How is it sloppy?  There is a 1:1 relationship between `print` statements and lines printed.  Also, a line that says `print` and then nothing would be expected to print a line of nothing.

Comment: out personal tastes differ. it's no problem, i like adam's solution.

Answer (score 1):

That's why I love python3:

```
print(*range(5), sep='\n',end='\n\n')
```

actually this is ugly:

```
for i in range(5)+['']:
    print i
```